# Using a custom function with tidyverse

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse

I created a dummy function to get the lag of one variable and I want to use it with other `tidyverse` functions. It works after I call `mutate` but not after calling `group_by`. It throws the following error: 
`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].`

Here is a repex:

```
#create a function to lag a selected variable
lag_func <- function(df, x) {
  mutate(df, lag = lag(df[,x])) 
}

#works
iris %>% 
  mutate(lead = lead(Petal.Length)) %>%
  lag_func('Petal.Length')

#doesn't work
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(lead = lead(Petal.Length)) %>%
  lag_func('Petal.Length')
```

Any idea what the error means and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to pass a column name as an argument to a `tidyverse` function is convert it to `quosure` using `enquo()`. See this code:

```
lag_func <- function(df, x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  mutate(df, lag = lag(!!x)) # !! is to evaluate rather than quoting (x)
}
```

Now let's try our function:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(lead = lead(Petal.Length)) %>%
  lag_func(Petal.Length)

# A tibble: 150 x 7
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  lead   lag
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.4  NA  
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    1.3   1.4
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    1.5   1.4
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    1.4   1.3
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.7   1.5
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa    1.4   1.4
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa    1.5   1.7
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    1.4   1.4
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    1.5   1.5
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    1.5   1.4
# ... with 140 more rows
```

For more info on how to use `tidyverse` functions within your custom functions see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: Thanks Abdallah! Quoting from the link you shared "enquo() uses some dark magic to look at the argument, see what the user typed, and return that value as a quosure." Also, I found this to be useful too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXS3ssntw