# Building custom function with tidyverse in R - can't make the enquo() work

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I have a data frame with predictions and observed values and they come from various datasets so, something like:

```
datasets = rep(1:4, each=5)
obs = runif(n=20, min=1, max=20)
pred = runif(n=20, min=1, max=20)
df = data.frame(datasets,obs,pred)
```

Now I want to make a custom function that uses tidyverse but the thing is definetly not happy. I looked at this: [Using a custom function with tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340768/using-a-custom-function-with-tidyverse)

Simply using tidyverse like this works:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hydroGOF)

# This works fine!
df %>%
    group_by(datasets) %>%
    reframe(result = rmse(obs,pred))
```

getting me this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  datasets result
     <int>  <dbl>
1        1   4.22
2        2   3.35
3        3   6.31
4        4   7.59
```

OK! But then I have my function it gives me an error

```
# but inside my function it is not happy!
make_calc = function(df,x,y,group){

    library(tidyverse)
    library(hydroGOF)        

    obs = enquo(x)
    pred = enquo(y)
    group= enquo(group)
    
    some_calc = df %>%
        group_by(!!group) %>%
        reframe(result = rmse(!!obs,!!pred))
    
    return(some_calc)
}

make_calc(df,'obs','pred','datasets')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `reframe()`:
ℹ In argument: `result = rmse("obs", "pred")`.
ℹ In group 1: `"datasets" = "datasets"`.
Caused by error in `rmse.default()`:
! Invalid argument type: 'sim' & 'obs' have to be of class: c('integer', 'numeric', 'ts', 'zoo')
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Looking at just the group_by bit it doesn't do what I'm expecting it would do but add a new column called 'Dataset

```
> df %>%
+         group_by(!!group)
# A tibble: 20 × 4
# Groups:   "dataset" [1]
   datasets   obs  pred `"dataset"`
      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
 1        1 16.7  13.6  dataset    
 2        1 15.9  19.7  dataset    
 3        1 18.5  14.7  dataset    
 4        1  5.44  1.38 dataset    
 5        1 13.3  19.1  dataset    
 6        2 16.6  15.4  dataset    
 7        2 16.7  17.3  dataset    
 8        2 19.9  13.1  dataset
 ...
```

Please help. :)

Comment: I can't run your code because `hydroGOF` isn't on CRAN any more (well, it's archived but needs a string of other archived packages installed to make it work). Isn't your problem just that you are calling the function with quoted names instead of symbols? For example, instead of `make_calc(df, 'obs', 'pred', 'datasets')` try  `make_calc(df, obs, pred, datasets)`

Comment: Thanks, @AllanCameron, I was not aware that hydroGOF is archived. Nonetheless, I didn't know I should not pass quoted! That solved it! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments the tidyevaluation syntax doesn't take character names of columns, even outside your function:

```r
library(tidyverse)


datasets = rep(1:4, each=5)
obs = runif(n=20, min=1, max=20)
pred = runif(n=20, min=1, max=20)
df = data.frame(datasets,obs,pred)

df |> 
  group_by("dataset")
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   "dataset" [1]
#>    datasets   obs  pred `"dataset"`
#>       <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
#>  1        1  7.15 19.9  dataset    
#>  2        1 16.7   7.93 dataset    
#>  3        1 13.7  17.0  dataset    
#>  4        1  3.27  5.73 dataset    
#>  5        1  6.22  5.71 dataset    
#>  ...
```

This returns the same as your `group_by(!!group)` line above when the `group` argument to your function is a string.

Passing to your function as unquoted arguments works (with a stand-in `rmse` function):

```r
make_calc = function(df,x,y,group){
  
  rmse <- function(a, b) {
    spe <- (a - b) ^ 2
    mspe <- mean(spe)
    sqrt(mspe)
  }
  
  obs = enquo(x)
  pred = enquo(y)
  group= enquo(group)
  
  some_calc = df %>%
    group_by(!!group) %>%
    reframe(result = rmse(!!obs,!!pred))
  
  return(some_calc)
}

make_calc(df, obs, pred, datasets)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   datasets result
#>      <int>  <dbl>
#> 1        1   7.17
#> 2        2   7.63
#> 3        3   9.22
#> 4        4   7.45
```